# NgRx Success Action not Dispatched

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm starting out with NgRx and trying to get a very simple scenario up and running.

**The problem:**

I have a very simple service that is for now just returning a hard coded string value that I want to display on the UI by dispatching a CREATE action. Upon success the CREATE_SUCCESS action should be triggered, but the CREATE_SUCCESS action is never triggered

I expose 3 actions

```
export const CREATE =                 '[Profile] Create';
export const CREATE_SUCCESS =         '[Profile] Create Success';
export const CREATE_FAIL =            '[Profile] Create Fail';

export class CreateAction implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE;

    constructor() { }
}

export class CreateSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE_SUCCESS;

    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}

export class CreateFailAction implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE_FAIL;

    constructor(public payload: any) { }
}
```

In the reducer I have the following

```
export interface State {
    loading: boolean;
    result: Observable<string>;
}

export const initialState: State = {
    loading: false,
    result: Observable.of('Default')
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: profile.Actions):State{
    switch (action.type) {
        case profile.CREATE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        }

        case profile.CREATE_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                result: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        }

        case profile.CREATE_FAIL: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
            };
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

In the effect I have the following

*Please note:* I moved the catch clause into the switchMap method as suggested in many other threads

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileEffects {
    @Effect() create$ = this._actions$
   .ofType(profile.CREATE)
   .switchMap(payload => this._profileService.create$()
       .map(res => ({ type: profile.CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: res }))
       .catch(e => Observable.of({ type: profile.CREATE_FAIL, payload: e })));

  constructor(
      private _profileService: ProfileService,
      private _actions$: Actions
  ) { }
}
```

In my component I dispatch the CreateAction

```
created$: Observable<string>;

 constructor
 (
     private _store: Store<any>,
     public navCtrl: NavController
 ) {
      this.created$ = this._store.select(s => s.profile.result.value);
 }

create_profile(){
    this._store.dispatch(new CreateAction());
}
```

and on the UI I have

```
<div>{{ created$ | async }}</div>
```

In the dev tools it is evident that on the CREATE action was dispatched, but no CREATE_SUCCESS action

[image]

There is no error messages displayed within the console.

Comment: Maybe the Effect is not recognizing `profile.CREATE` - try `.ofType('[Profile] Create')`

Comment: I don't see `export type Actions = CreateAction | CreateSuccessAction | CreateFailAction` on your Actions code. Do you have that in your code?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't include it in this thread, but I have it in my code

Comment: So the only logical conclusion I can see is that `this._profileService.create$()` is not producing a value. Have you done any debugging in the `switchMap` to test it?

Comment: Make sure you import 
EffectsModule.forRoot([ProfileEffects]), in your module

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following change:

```
.switchMap(payload => this._profileService.create$())
.map(res => ({ type: profile.CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: res })
```

By moving the parantheses, it calls `map` on the `action` itself, and not on the result of `create$`. This will map the CREATE into a CREATE_SUCCESS

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried both scenarios before, 1) Where the map is called on the action itself and 2) Where map is called on the service call. Both these scenarios yield the same result. If I can just see some error message it might help, but at the moment, it's just not dispatching the SUCCESS action

Comment: Interesting... If you add some logging into the `map`, is it definitely being invoked?

Comment: Tried using the .do method and added a console.log to the map method, the console however stays empty, not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Logically, that should be exactly the same since `.switchMap(...)` returns whatever the inner observable `this._profileService.create$()` produces. It sounds like that inner observable is not producing. What happens if you `.do(x => console.log(x))` ***before*** the `switchMap()`?